Altering load-bearing wall
I've got a load-bearing 2 × 6 wall in my basement. For a bathroom remodel, I need to move one stud 3.5 inches to the right to accommodate a niche to be centered. Should I double up on the one stud I move? There are two floors above me. Do I need a header?

does adding a new one 3.5" off the previous one such that you maintain the maximum 16" oc spacing work out or interfer with your niche?

Do you have layouts and picture?    Are you in the US?    There are very very few load bearing walls in basements.    There might be a wall that hides something that is load bearing but seldom is a wall the point load for what is upstairs.

If there are support posts holding up a beam, inside of that wall, then moving a stud over a few inches should not bother anything.  No support posts and it gets more interesting.
